# Selenium webscraping using CSS selectors to extract

Tags: javascript, python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I know basic scraping using requests and Beautiful Soup but I don't know much about Selenium Webdriver. The page uses a lot of JavaScript and I am able to grab everything except image and product URLs. I just want to know how to grab the URLs and other things together and append them into a list.

> Assignment 1: Data Extraction (Mandatory) Develop a Python script
> (scraper.py) using Selenium and Chromedriver to extract data on
> women's jackets from the Patagonia brand across the following
> platforms:
>
> - **Patagonia: https://www.patagonia.com**
>
> Ensure the script is scalable and adaptable for additional platforms
> in the future. Perform necessary post-processing to filter out and
> exclude products that do not fall under the category of women's
> jackets. Compile the data into a CSV file with the following columns:
>
> - product title
> - product URL
> - product image URL
> - product price
> - rating (if available)
> - review count (if available).
>
> Ensure that the CSV file maintains consistency across all platforms,
> handling cases where certain information may not be available.
> Development Guidelines:
>
> - **The script should use concise CSS paths for efficient data extraction**.
> - Include clear documentation and maintain a structure that allows for easy expansion and adaptability.
> - If a platform does not show ratings and reviews in product search results, these two columns can be left blank in the CSV file.

```py
def fetch():
    items = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('#product-search-results > div.row.product-grid.load-more-present')

while True:
    try:
        load_more_button = WebDriverWait(driver, 30).until(EC.presence_of_all_elements_located('#product-search-results > div.row.product-grid.load-more-present > div.col-12.grid-footer > div > div > button')))
        driver.execute_script("arguments[0].scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'auto', block: 'center' });", load_more_button)
        load_more_button.click()
        pages = fetch() 
    except (TimeoutException, NoSuchElementException) as e:
        pages = fetch()
        print("Error:", e)
        break
```

I tried absolute_links but it did not work. I expected img and products url links.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
# ...
driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR, '#product-search-results > div.row.product-grid.load-more-present')
```

See [Selenium Docs - Locating Elements](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html)

You can also use `driver.find_elements(...)` to return a list if you expect multiple elements to match your selector.

Comment: Thank you for the source. Can you tell me "use css paths for efficient extraction" mean?. Does it mean I need to use CSS selectors or I can use xpath?